# Scalding: Parse nested JSON file with differing attributes

Tags: json, scala, parsing, scalding

I have a nested JSON file where each record may contain a different set of fields in the nested portion.   The fiel looks like this although this is really the avro version:

```
{"type":"record",
 "name":"features",
 "namespace":"OurCode",
 "fields":[{"name":"key","type":"long"},
       {"name":"features",
        "type":{"type":"map","values":"double"}}]
}
```

The second field, "features", is a nested field that contains multiple fields inside of it and each record contains a potentially different set of nested fields.

So if I have 2 records that look like this:

```
key1: 123   features:{var1=4, var2 = 3, var4 = 10}
key2: 456   features:{var3 = 15, var4 = 9, var5 = 22}
```

I need to turn the above data into something that looks like:

```
Key     Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Var5
123       1      3     0      10     0
456       0      0     15      9     22
```

I can manually extract the fields when I read in the file using something like:

```
JsonLine(args("input"), ('acct_id, Symbol("features.Var1"). Symbol("features.Var2), ...)
  .read
```

I'd like some code that is a little more generic and can figure out what all the sub fields are without me having to explicity declare each of them.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

JsonLine doesn't have the kind of functionality you are looking for, I have read there source code and examples and couldn't find something like that.

Infact i was also exploring on the same front for past few days and couldn't find any good json parsers. JsonLine is tedious but does the job excellently.